# Response body is empty in http call

Tags: flutter, dart

I am calling a remote PHP file to get some data into my Flutter app.

This is the Flutter function:

```
 Future<void> registrarUsuario() async {


    var url = Constantes.adminUsuariosUrl + 'nuevo_usuario.php';
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      "email": controllerEmail.text,
      "password": controllerPass.text
    });

    print("response ${response.body}");

  }
```

Calling the function the print output is empty.

```
flutter: response
```

But calling the PHP file using Postman gives me the following output:

```
[{"id":"57","correo":"modestovasco@gmail.com"}]
```

I would like to update the funtion registrarUsuario to get the json objects from the response.body

Comment: are you sure you don't need any header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the body content in request

```dart
 Future<void> registrarUsuario() async {


    var url = Constantes.adminUsuariosUrl + 'nuevo_usuario.php';
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body:json.encode({
      "email": controllerEmail.text,
      "password": controllerPass.text
    }));

    print("response ${response.body}");

  }
```

Comment: Updating the function like to propose makes no changes to the response

Comment: Check for the response code. Is success code? Check for any error in `php`.

Comment: I guess the server is not allowing POSTS requests.

Comment: That's fine. Encoding the json is must in body of the request.